# Le « poste de numéro un » (d'un parti politique, d'un gouvernement) ?

Tags: vocabulaire, france, politique

J'ai lu qu'une personne était un *ex-candidat au **poste de numéro un** d'un parti*. On trouve la locution nominale *[numéro](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/num%C3%A9ro) un* au TLFi pour « le membre le plus important (d'un gouvernement, d'un pays, d'un groupement politique) ». J'avais compris mais est-ce vraiment un « poste » dans un groupement politique/gouvernement ? Je suis davantage habitué à comprendre la locution comme signifiant [*chef de file*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8869731), où à la retrouver en locution adjectivale (*ennemi numéro un*), et dans le contexte je me serais attendu (au Canada) à trouver ex-candidat de la [*course à la chefferie/direction*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8354619) du parti... Ensuite ailleurs je lis qu'une autre personne était le « numéro 2 » de telle autre personne, et qu'elle provenait d'une société qui était *numéro 2* mondial dans tel domaine.

---

Au point où je me demande s'il est plus usuel dans le paysage politique français de dire *numéro un/deux/2* etc. que *chef* ou de la désigner par la fonction effective (le cas échéant) ou la provenance (circonscription).

- Le *numéro un* est-il un *poste* dans un parti ou un gouvernement et est-ce courant (dans le vocabulaire politique français) ?
- Est-il plus courant d'entendre parler du *numéro un* d'un parti etc.
  que du *chef* ; y a-t-il une nuance dans l'emploi selon qu'il s'agisse d'un parti ou d'un gouvernement ; dit-on *course au poste de numéro un* (d'un parti) ?

Comment: *[Chefferie](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chefferie)* n'est plus employé en France mais semble l'être au Quebec..

Comment: @jlliagre Oui, « définitivement », merci !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Numéro un* est un terme **courant**, surtout dans le milieu journalistique, parce que cette locution peut être utilisée lorsqu'il y a une incertitude sur la dénomination correcte à utiliser (ou alors que préciser le poste exact n'apporte pas d'information). On peut ainsi dire *numéro un* pour parler:

- d'un PDG
- d'un leader de mouvement idéologique
- d'un chef d'entreprise qui n'est pas techniquement PDG
- d'un chef de parti politique
- etc

Même avantage pour *numéro deux*: il n'y a pas à se poser la question *c'est quoi son poste officiel dans la structure?*

Etant donné que le *numéro un* n'est donc pas un poste à proprement parler, l'expression *course au poste de numéro un* est **correcte mais légèrement bancale**.

Answer (score 1):

« Numéro un » n'est pas une désignation spécifique, elle est très générale ; la nuance récente que le terme semble avoir acquise a été à n'en pas douter introduite sans modification de sens à partir de l'américain. Cela se voit aux dates d'attestation de son apparition dans les textes dans le [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/num%C3%A9ro) ; cette nuance est précisée dans la sous-définition même du TLFi : « Le membre le plus important (d'un gouvernement, d'un pays, d'un groupement politique) ».  Comme en américain ce terme ne constitue jamais un nom de fonction, mais il sert dans des contextes « choisis » pour référer à une personne dont le poste dans la hiérarchie d'une organisation est celui de plus haut responsable.  Comme on peut le déduire de l'entrée que le TLFi fournit pour « numéro un » (attestations à partir des années 70), et d'une certaine habitude des contextes où on le trouve, c'est un terme qui jusqu'à un passé récent n'a pas dénoté un rang dans une hiérarchie de commandement, mais un rang dans un contexte d'importances relatives, et il est toujours perpétué dans cette fonction. La dernière mode en France, pour référer aux chefs de file des partis politique c'est d'utiliser le mot « **patron** » ; cependant le terme formel, le nom de la fonction reste «**président**» ; « patron » est un mot qui a été utilisé depuis très longtemps pour tout propriétaire d'un commerce et aussi, très traditionnellement pour le chef d'un service médical dans un hôpital, en particulier un service médical de recherche. Voilà un terme qui dans le domaine des partis politiques, s'il n'a toujours pas le statut de nom de fonction, a l'avantage d'une congénialité bien plus grande que l'appellation « numéro un » en fait de terme de référence générale, l'emploi de ce dernier n'étant que passager dans ce contexte.

Pour un président de la nation les termes « **chef de l'état** » et « **président de la république** » sont courants et dominent largement. « Numéro un » n'est pas utilisé. Le terme « **chef du gouvernement** » désigne ce qui est aussi appelé « **premier ministre** » le plus souvent, ceci étant le nom formel de la fonction.(Un autre ministre que le premier ministre est parfois nommé chef du gouvernement.)  « Numéro un » serait assez souvent utilisé dans la presse pour cette fonction.

Comment: *Numéro un du gouvernement* est couramment employé pour désigner le premier ministre (https://www.francetvinfo.fr/politique/remaniement/bernard-cazeneuve-un-fidele-du-president-a-matignon_1956479.html), mais c'est parfois le ministre ayant le rang le plus élevé sous le premier ministre, le ministre d'état cité en premier lors de la lecture des membres d'un nouveau gouvernement (https://www.francetvinfo.fr/politique/la-composition-du-gouvernement-fillon-iii-a-ete-annoncee-dimanche-soir-a-l-elysee-par-claude-gueant_231503.html)

Comment: Cette désignation cependant est assez accessoire, appositive ; il me semble que l'on ne trouve pas couramment «  numéro un du gouvernement » en fonction sujet ou complément,  n'est-ce pas votre avis ? Ne serait utilisé dans ce contexte presque uniquement que « premier ministre » ou « chef du gouvernement ».

Comment: 1: Ne me vouvoie pas, s'il te plait. Il n'y a pas de hiérarchie dans stackexchange et nous sommes tous des "pairs" ici.  2: Fait attention aux liens inutilisables de tes réponses. Quand tu cites le TLFi, met un lien vers le TLFi, pas le lien temporaire du moteur de recherche que tu as utilisé. 3: Il me semble que *numéro un du gouvernement* et plus encore *numéro deux du gouvernement* sont souvent employés dans la presse écrite ou audiovisuelle, mais je n'ai pas de chiffres.

Comment: @jlliagreJe ne tutoie personne ; d'ailleurs je ne vois pas pourquoi imposer des coutumes spéciales seulement parce que l'on communique à distance et chambouler ainsi les habitudes profondes des gens ; pour moi le web ce n'est pas une nouvelle vie et rien de spécial n'y figure qu'il faille que j'utilise « tu » avec le ministre qui occasionnellement pourra être à l'autre bout puis « vous » avec le balayeur dans la rue parce qu'il n'est pas mon « esclave » (dira-t-il). La vie sur le web, c'est la vie qui continue. (Je trouve cette notion de « pair » forcée, artificielle dans le présent contexte.)

Comment: Je n'impose rien( j'ai écrit "s'il te plait") mais je ne vais pas te vouvoyer pour autant. Je trouve le vouvoiement ridicule et déplacé dans un forum ou équivalent.On n'est pas à la cour de Versailles. Les habitudes profondes des gens, même "avant" Internet, c'était quand même souvent de se tutoyer entre membres du même "club".

Comment: Non, bien sûr, je n'ai absolument aucune raison de même insinuer que vous l'imposez ; il n'y rien dans votre commentaire qui insinuerait quoi que ce soit de cette sorte ; mais, il n'y a pas de doute qu'il existe une force qui pousse à l'abandon de la deuxième personne, la même qui vous a converti à cette nouvelle façon d'agir. Ça ne me dérange pas d'être tutoyé par des inconnus et je ne vous ai jamais fais la moindre remarque à ce sujet ni ne vous en ferai jamais. Je n'exige pas le vouvoiement non plus, mais j'entends préserver mes habitudes, que je ne trouve pas ridicules.

Comment: Je n'ai pas été *converti* à quoi que ce soit. Bien avant que les réseaux sociaux existent, j'ai toujours tutoyé les élèves avec qui j'était scolarisé, mes collègues de travail, mes amis et les membres des clubs auxquels j'ai appartenu, etc. De plus, FSE étant souvent utilisé par de non francophones, le vouvoiement ajoute inutilement une difficulté supplémentaire, ces visiteurs pouvant se sentir obligés de se conformer à cet usage.

Comment: @jlliagre J'ai pourtant lu plusieurs fois que la coutume avait été introduite sur les forums internet comme si le forum internet avait des caractéristiques à rendre cela légitime ; les forum internet ne sont rien d'autre que des forums télévisés où l'activité est plus intense et ce sont aussi, pour un grand nombre de ces forums des endroits où on y trouve la langue la plus vulgaire et où  l'obscénité dans le langage est bien plus courante qu'ailleurs (FSE mis à part, autrement je n'y serais plus déjà).